# how to convert dataframe to jsonobject per user(group_by user) using R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr

i have a dataframe.

[image]

```
df1 <- data.frame('user'=c('user1', 'user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user2', 'user3'),
                     'type'=c('a','a','a','b','b','a'),
                     'item'=c('item1','item2','item3','item2','item3','item3'),
                     'weight'=c(1.5,2,3,0,4,5))
```

This is part of the df, there are actually almost 120000 rows.

I want to create a new dataframe(df2) like below.
[image]

1. df1 %>% group_by(user)
2. create json object per user
   like:
   {"user":"user1", "itemArray":[{"item":"item1", "type":"a", "weight":1.5},{"item":"item2", "type":"a", "weight":2.0},{"item":"item3", "type":"a", "weight":3.0}], "timestamp":current_timestamp}
   {"user":"user2", "itemArray":[{"item":"item2", "type":"b", "weight":0.0},{"item":"item3", "type":"b", "weight":4.0}], "timestamp":current_timestamp}
   {"user":"user3", "itemArray":[{"item":"item3", "type":"a", "weight":5.0}], "timestamp":current_timestamp}
3. create new df2

How to make df2 without for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach with  `purrr` and `jsolite`:

```
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

split(df1, ~ user) %>%
  imap(~ list(user = .y, itemArray = .x[, -1]) %>%
           toJSON()) %>%
  tibble::tibble(user = names(.), JSON = .)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  user  JSON        
  <chr> <named list>
1 user1 <json [1]>  
2 user2 <json [1]>  
3 user3 <json [1]>  

# Containing JSON:

# {"user":["user1"],"itemArray":[{"type":"a","item":"item1","weight":1.5},{"type":"a","item":"item2","weight":2},{"type":"a","item":"item3","weight":3}]}
# {"user":["user2"],"itemArray":[{"type":"b","item":"item2","weight":0},{"type":"b","item":"item3","weight":4}]}
# {"user":["user3"],"itemArray":[{"type":"a","item":"item3","weight":5}]}
```

(Data used:)

```
df1 <- structure(list(user = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", "user2", "user3"), type = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a"), item = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item2", "item3", "item3"), weight = c(1.5, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```